# Can not find Resource files

Tags: intellij-idea

I have the following project structure in IntelliJ IDEA:

[image]

But when I run the code it throws an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
```

Because I am loading image using the Main.Class.getResources() method and it seems it doesn't find then in the Resources folder. I tried to add the *.png pattern to compiler settings, but it doesn't work. Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues that I see; one being an IntelliJ problem, the other being a general naming problem.

First, you should mark the folder as a resources folder - right click on it and select "Mark Directory As" -> "Resources folder".

Next, make your resources folder name lowercase.  Even if you're on a case insensitive platform, not having to deal with casing issues will make your life simpler.